# android studio how to set a fragment from navigation activity as startup page

Tags: java, android, fragment

Currently im using fragment_empty as startup.
[fragment_empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49p2.png)
I want fragment_home as startup-page(when you start up the app), but i don't want [fragment_home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5YDq.png) to be seen on every page.

**The fragment_home page :**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welkom op home!"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="218dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

**The fragment_empty page:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

**My MainActivity (the navigation drawer):**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_evenementen) {
            fragment = new EvenementenFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
            fragment = new ContactFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

App_bar_main page :

```
<include layout="@layout/fragment_empty" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your MainActivity onCreate() method you can directly call first time HomeFragment like

```
HomeFragment mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, mHomeFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `add` instead of `replace`

In your `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method add:

```
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

This will add your fragment's xml to your `frame_container`. To change `Fragments`, just use the same method as you already have defined in your code.

Comment: Np. Good luck with your Deveopment!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the above code like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    //Here the Code 


HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    }
```